# Problem with installing php7.1-gd

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

I am running on debian9 and using `ppa:ondrej/php` repository, but I am unable to install php7.1. nor install missing dependecies. When I try to install it with `apt install php7.1-gd` I've got this error.

```
apt-get install php7.1-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.1-gd : Depends: libgd3 (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and here is error what happends when I try to install `libgd3`

```
apt install libgd3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgd3 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.24-11+deb9u4 is to be installed
          Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12.6) but 2.11.0-6.7+b1 is to be installed
          Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use the PPA on Debian 9, use the appropriate repositories, as described in [Ondrej’s `README.txt`](https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt):

```
sudo apt-get -y install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
sudo apt-get update
```

That will allow you to install `php7.1-gd` with dependencies which can be satisfied in Debian 9.

Comment: I still get the error:
`$ sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php7.1-gd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'php7.1-gd' has no installation candidate`

Comment: What does `apt policy php7.1-gd` output? What about `lsb_release -sc`?

Comment: I'm trying to move on without it, thanks for the commands that could shed some light into it. 
`$ apt policy php7.1-gd
php7.1-gd:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     7.1.28-1+0~20190412071216.17+stretch~1.gbpbe9b36 -1
        500 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch/main amd64 Packages
`

`$ lsb_release -sc
stretch`

Comment: Your pin preferences are preventing its installation.

Comment: Thanks @stephen-kitt I'll dig into that

Answer (score -1):

You can find package from here:

http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-2_amd64.deb
```